# I want the blue bits of the buttons to all be the same length as each other

Tags: html, css

I want the blue bits of the buttons to all be the same length as each other so it looks cool in a column instead of all messy

context context context

```css
.button {
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  background: #70D4C7;
  padding: 3.5px 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  text-shadow: #70D4C7 0 1px 0;
  font-size: 20.5px;
  font-family: Fira Sans;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="button">
    <a href="#" style="color: black" class="button"><strong>Homepage</strong></a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" style="color: black" class="button"> <strong>exampleexample</strong>
    </a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" style="color: black" class="button"><strong>example  </strong></a>
    </nav>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `display:block` and remove the `<br>` tags (use `margin-bottom` instead if you need space)

Comment: You have an orphaned `</nav>`  tag.  Also, why are you styling links as buttons?  That's generally thought to be poor design.  Buttons should be buttons and links should be links.

Comment: For more nitpicky feedback: `border-radius` doesn't need vendor prefixes any more, `vertical-align` does nothing here (your `padding` handles that just fine) and you should quote and provide a fallback for the font like `font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;`

Comment: it worked, thanks lads

Comment: okay will do mate

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each link in a div:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" style="color: black" class="button"><strong>Homepage</strong></a>
</div>
```

Remove the `<br/>` tags.  And add the following CSS (notice, I moved the background color from your CSS segment to here):

```
#button > div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #70D4C7;
}

#button {
  width: 40%;
}
```

NOTE:  It is generally considered to be poor coding style to use elements for purposes other than which they were intended.  So, for example, buttons should be used as buttons, and links should be used as links.  Links should not be styled as buttons.  But, if you insist on your current structure, the above modifications will produce the following effect:

[image: result]

[Here is a Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/otcjad1c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` is by default `display:inline`, so it can not have a width. Just add to the class `button` :

```
.button{
     width:200px;
     display:block;
}
```

and your problem is solved.